# How to find all services/application owned by different groups and users

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

What would be the way to print/list all services/application owned by different groups and users in the linux ? Which command supposed to use for that?

Appreciate for your help in advance

Thanks
Umesh Narayanan A V

Answer (score 0):

They should be listed in `/etc/init.d`

or this may be help your question:

```
systemctl -l --type service --all
```

if they not works you can look at manual page of `systemctl` command.